# Solve non-linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a non-linear differential equation of the form-

$$
  A \ddot{x} + B \dot{x}^2 + C x = \dot{u} + u^2
$$

In the above $u$ is the external input and the output signal is $x$. I can solve the system numerically by putting in a sigal in place of $u$ say $u(t)=u_0\sin{\omega t}$ or any other function. But what if I want to put in a generalised function in place of $u$ say $u(t) = \frac{b_0}{2} + \sum{a_n}\sin{\omega_n t} + \sum{b_n}\cos{\omega_n t}$ using Fourier's series? Please provide me a generalised framework for the process.

Comment: If the left side simulates a mechanical system, a spring with some kind of air resistance, the middle term has to be $c|\dot x|\,\dot x$.

Comment: And if you set $m\dot x=y+u$, the you get a first-order system $\dot x=(y+u)/m$, $\dot y+c/m^2|y+u|(y+u)+kx=u^2$ that does not contain derivatives of the control input.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I did not intend to simulate a mechanical spring-mass-damper system with this equation. Maybe there is some coincidence because of the constants m,c and k. I am changing the coeeficients to A, B and C to make the problem look generalised.

Comment: You need to tell more on what you want to achieve with these Fourier expressions. Do you want to find $x$ also as Fourier series? Do you know the effect of non.linear terms on the spectrum? Because just for numerical integration, you simply use the formula as-is, with its term-wise derivative.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, I want to achieve $x$ as Fourier Series. Instead of putting a particular signal as $u$ time and again and solving it numerically, I want to get a general expression of $x$ from the general form of $u$.